# How can I manually copy a deployment build of ASP.NET Core application to Azure web application (App Service)

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Core (5) application which is a Webapi application which also hosts React static files.
I have built the application and I can start it on my machine and it works fine with Kestrel.
I have created an appropriate web application (Azure App Service) on Azure and configured it to use .NET 5 on Linux.
How can I manually copy the files (executable, runtime and React static files) to my App Service?

If this is not possible then is there an alternative Azure service that I could use (besides having a virtual machine)?

Answer (score 0):

Just zip the content and visit https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI where <app_name> is the name of your web app and upload the file inside wwwroot folder (drag and drop the zip file).

As another option, try access Kudu portal using Azure Portal:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I go to that link I just the following in my browser: 'Service Unavailable'. Is there anything special I need to do to enable this?

Comment: no, it should work fine, unless the website is stopped

Comment: It tells me that its running in the service overview.

Comment: try to access it using Azure Portal, I've uploaded an image

Comment: I tried and I get the same error. I've actually now deleted the app and I will recreate it. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: I just wanted to inform you that I've created a new app and scm works fine now. However if I go to /ZipDeployUI I get 'No route registered for '/ZipDeployUI'',

Comment: what if you go using the Azure portal as in my print screen?

Comment: I think the problem is that I have a Linux app service plan. In any case I've managed to do it manually. I just unpacked my zip to /home/site/wwwroot together with a web.config file and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is the problem. All *.scm.* urls for my application return 'Service unavailable' in the browser (just this single pair of words in white color on gray background).
I've finally delete the application and I will create it again.